# xss vulnerability on careers.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, xss

[A Reddit article with a demonstration of a XSS vulnerability on careers.stackoverflow.com](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/dwtou/stack_overflow_how_do_i_leave_my_site_vulnerable/)

Unsure if this is duplicate - have searched a handful of ways on meta -- "xss careers" and more, but had no results on meta.

[image]

Comment: This fixed? I cannot repro in Chrome or IE8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been fixed, thank you for the heads-up.